# Instantiate a fragment from String?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to let users configure a ViewPager. Right now I'm saving a class as a string in an array.

```
EditableListItem fragment = new EditableListItem(R.string.dialer, Dialer.class.toString(), this);
```

I want to retrieve the class as a string and add it to the viewpager. In pseudocode it would be something like:

```
String s = fragment.getClass();
Fragment f = new Fragment.fromString(s);
mPagerAdapter.addFragment(f);
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String fragmentName = "fragment"
Fragment fragment = null;

try {
    Class<?> fragmentClass = Class.forName(fragmentName);
    fragment = (Fragment)fragmentClass.newInstance();                                           
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

mPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment)
```

You can instantiate a class from a string like this.

Or you can use the following method if you are supporting API Level 11 and up, or possibly using the support library (not sure on that):
[Fragment.instantiate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly however I noticed Dialer.class.toString() returns "class com.example..." so it's creating an error. Do you know how to get the class without the word "class"? (if not I can simply use substring)

Comment: Just checked, you can use class.getName() to get the class without the 'class' keyword.

Comment: throwing class not found exception